# simple html dom and a ? in the url

Tags: php, html

When I try to use the following code:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$url = "http://www.example.com/changeCity.php?city=NewYork=";

$html->load_file($url);
```

it loads `http://www.example.com/changeCity.php`.

How do I get it to load for `NewYork city?`

I know what the entire URL is, it's just that I don't know how to handle it when it has a `?` in it.

************EDIT*********************

I'm still not having much luck.  The above code actually loads http://www.example.com/index.php - I made an error above.  The changeCity.php?city=NewYork= should change the city to New York, however this will still be under the url http://www.example.com/index.php.  All cities have the same url - http://www.example.com/index.php.

What's happening is that the code is indeed loading http://www.example.com/index.php but it always defaults to the default city, basically the change city doesn't work.  I've tried for other cities as well, not just New York but the loaded url always defaults back to the default city.  For some reason the code does not recognize the ? which redirects the url.

The trailing = doesn't make a difference, I've tried the code with and without the =.

Any ideas?

Comment: It should work the way you show, just the trailing `=` isn't necessary. What exactly does not work?

Comment: No reason it shouldn't work. Unless example.com is checking UA or something.

Comment: @Pekka: The querystring is elided, as the question states.

Comment: Is the issue about the space in `NewYork city` then? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to urlencode $url?

```
$url = urlencode("http://www.example.com/changeCity.php?city=NewYork");
```

Comment: Don't `urlencode` the complete URL, only the query string you want to send.

Comment: The only character worth encoding is the trailing `=`, but that's probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `simple_html_dom` does, but what you could try:

```
$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));
```

`str_get_html` is part of that PHP lib. Second tab ("How to modify HTML elements?") on http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You should indeed remove or encode the trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

This will load changeCity.php, and pass `NewYork=` as a variable in the $_GET array. You can do something with that variable. In other words `$_GET['city'] == NewYork=`.

If you want to load a page that has a filename of NewYork, then you could do something like:

```
// changeCity.php
$page = $_GET['city'];
// secure $page variable
incude($page . '.php');
```

I'm pretty sure you understand this, but the OP is not entirely clear.

Comment: @steve Have you fixed it now?